# Bindtooltip on hover and permanent in leaflet

Tags: leaflet

Is it possible to bind 2 different tooltips on a polygon in leaflet?
One on hover and the other set to permanent.
Right now in my code it's taking only one.

Comment: which one your code is showing ? on hover?

Answer (score 4):

You can bind any number of tooltips. Answering your specific question, you can define one tooltip to be permanent.

```
L.rectangle([[48.84, 2.34], [48.86, 2.36]]).bindTooltip("test", {
    permanent: true
}).addTo(map);

L.rectangle([[48.84, 2.34], [48.86, 2.36]]).bindTooltip("hello", {
    permanent: false
}).addTo(map););
```

See an example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/9d9pcL1a/

Comment: I suspect OP initially wanted the 2 tooltips on the very same layer, not 2 different like in your example, even though they overlap.